# pass data between browser and java SE project using websocket

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, websocket, jetty-9

I created a sample project using Java and JavaScript. Java is used to create the server part and JavaScript is used for client part. I have used [jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty) version 9.0.5 to develop javaSE project.
This is my server part:

```
package com.websocet;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletFactory;


public class WebSocketTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try{
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        WebSocketHandler wsHandler = new WebSocketHandler() {
            @Override
            public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
                factory.register(MyWebSocketHandler.class);
            }
        };
        server.setHandler(wsHandler);
        server.start();        
        server.join();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error "+ e);
        }
    }
}
```

This my MyWebSocketHandler class

```
package com.websocet;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketClose;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketConnect;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketError;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketMessage;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocket;

public class MyWebSocketHandler {

    @OnWebSocketClose
    public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
        System.out.println("Close: statusCode=" + statusCode + ", reason=" + reason);
    }

    @OnWebSocketError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + t.getMessage());
    }

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    public void onConnect(Session session) {
        
        System.out.println("Connect: " + session.getRemoteAddress().getAddress());
        try {
            session.getRemote().sendString("Hello Webbrowser");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error -----" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Message: " + message);
    }
}
```

This is my client part:

```
console.log("start index.js");

var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/");

ws.onopen = function() {
    console.log("Opened!");
    ws.send("Hello Server");
};

ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    console.log("Message: " + evt.data);
};

ws.onclose = function() {
    console.log("connection Closed...");
};

ws.onerror = function(err) {
    console.log("Error"+ err);
};
```

when I run the server part it works well.

```
2015-12-11 12:02:31.081:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.0.5.v20130815
2015-12-11 12:02:31.141:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@470e2030{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
```

But after I run client part, the server throws below exception.

```
2015-12-11 12:02:42.055:WARN:oejs.HttpChannel:qtp769287236-18: /
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.InvalidWebSocketException: com.websocet.MyWebSocketHandler does not implement org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketListener or declare @WebSocket
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.EventDriverFactory.wrap(EventDriverFactory.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory.acceptWebSocket(WebSocketServerFactory.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketHandler.handle(WebSocketHandler.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I downloaded **jetty-distribution-9.0.5.v2013081**5 and added it in to **eclipse IDE**.
I am new to web socket. So please help me to resolve this problem. My goal is getting data from my web browser and passing it into my JavaSE project. If anyone knows to do this please let me know.

Comment: I guess you need to learn to read the output: `com.websocet.MyWebSocketHandler does not implement org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WebSocketListener or declare @WebSocket`

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my question. I had missed an annotation. It has to be corrected as **`@WebSocket`**

```
@WebSocket
public class MyWebSocketHandler {

  ......

}
```